# MSVC Name mangling and linking (using Bullet Physics)

Tags: c++, linker, bulletphysics, name-mangling

I am trying to use the Bullet Physics engine in my project and have a problem during linking.

This symbol is not available (linker error):

> ""void * __cdecl btAlignedAllocInternal(unsigned __int64,int)" (?btAlignedAllocInternal@@YAPEAX_KH@Z)" in Funktion ""public: static void * __cdecl btCollisionObject::operator new(unsigned __int64)" (??2btCollisionObject@@SAPEAX_K@Z)"

I used

> E:\SDKs\bullet-2.82-r2704\lib>dumpbin /symbols BulletDynamics.lib | findstr /R /
>   C:"btAlignedAllocInternal"

to check if the symbol is available, result:

> 17F 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     |
>   ?btAlignedAllocInternal@@YAPAXIH @Z (void * __cdecl
>   btAlignedAllocInternal(unsigned int,int)) 121 00000000 UNDEF  notype
>   ()    External     | ?btAlignedAllocInternal@@YAPAXIH @Z (void *
>   __cdecl btAlignedAllocInternal(unsigned int,int)) 07A 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | ?btAlignedAllocInternal@@YAPAXIH @Z (void
>   * __cdecl btAlignedAllocInternal(unsigned int,int)) 0AF 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | ?btAlignedAllocInternal@@YAPAXIH @Z (void
>   * __cdecl btAlignedAllocInternal(unsigned int,int)) 0B6 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | ?btAlignedAllocInternal@@YAPAXIH @Z (void
>   * __cdecl btAlignedAllocInternal(unsigned int,int)) 07F 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | ?btAlignedAllocInternal@@YAPAXIH @Z (void
>   * __cdecl btAlignedAllocInternal(unsigned int,int)) 308 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | ?btAlignedAllocInternal@@YAPAXIH @Z (void
>   * __cdecl btAlignedAllocInternal(unsigned int,int)) 16B 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | ?btAlignedAllocInternal@@YAPAXIH @Z (void
>   * __cdecl btAlignedAllocInternal(unsigned int,int)) 279 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | ?btAlignedAllocInternal@@YAPAXIH @Z (void
>   * __cdecl btAlignedAllocInternal(unsigned int,int)) 2C7 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | ?btAlignedAllocInternal@@YAPAXIH @Z (void
>   * __cdecl btAlignedAllocInternal(unsigned int,int)) 3C6 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | ?btAlignedAllocInternal@@YAPAXIH @Z (void
>   * __cdecl btAlignedAllocInternal(unsigned int,int)) 249 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | ?btAlignedAllocInternal@@YAPAXIH @Z (void
>   * __cdecl btAlignedAllocInternal(unsigned int,int)) 675 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | ?btAlignedAllocInternal@@YAPAXIH @Z (void
>   * __cdecl btAlignedAllocInternal(unsigned int,int)) 39E 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | ?btAlignedAllocInternal@@YAPAXIH @Z (void
>   * __cdecl btAlignedAllocInternal(unsigned int,int)) 24D 00000000 UNDEF  notype ()    External     | ?btAlignedAllocInternal@@YAPAXIH @Z (void
>   * __cdecl btAlignedAllocInternal(unsigned int,int))

To me, it looks like the symbol is not available (not matching mangled names), but I have to confess, I do not actually know how the mangled symbol names are created.

Can you explain where the differences between YAPAXIH and YAPEAX_KH?
Or does anyone have an other suggestion what might be wrong?

Comment: Look at demangler: http://demangler.com/ BTW, usually linker problems are solved by more simple way. For example, did you add .lib file to the linker dependencies list?

Comment: Thank you for demangler.com. Yes, if I delete the .lib, I get an other error.

Comment: Some problems with bitness? Looking at demangled functions you posted, maybe it is about x86 - x64 compatibility.

Comment: Might be so, I use the same compiler on the same machine, but I'll have a look.

Comment: size_t is different in x86 and x64 builds. Maybe you build x64, and .lib and .dll are for x86 (Win32).

Comment: Yes. However it happened, I did a x86 build for bullet...

Answer (score 2):

Name mangling seems to be rather obscure for MSVC. I used [demangler.com](http://demangler.com/) and got the following:

for ?btAlignedAllocInternal@@YAPEAX_KH@Z

> void * __ptr64 __cdecl btAlignedAllocInternal(unsigned __int64,int)

for ?btAlignedAllocInternal@@YAPAXIH@Z

> void * __cdecl btAlignedAllocInternal(unsigned int,int)

The function definition is

```
void* btAlignedAllocInternal(size_t size, int alignment);
```

This clearly indicates that a x64/x86 issue exists. Indeed, bullet was build using x86.